# Moved wordpress content posts, pages, media doesn't show up

Tags: database, wordpress, missing-data, migrating

I have had a wordpress website go down from DNS issues and I moved it manually to a new host and database. I updated the database info to match the new database and uploaded the exported tables from the old website to the new wordpress installation.

Unfortunately, none of the posts, pages and content show up in the new wordpress website. When I look in the new database all the tables are updated to match the old. does anyone have any thing I haven't thought of?

Hosting: GoDaddy Managed wordpress hosting http://0vg.e15.myftpupload.com/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress stores images in the database with their full URLs.

[image: WP Image In Database]

It's my suspicion that your re-hosted site is still pointing to the old CDN – and by extension – old, DNS-downed domain.

You might backup your database, and try experiment with a query like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid=(REPLACE (guid, 'old-dns.com/wp-content/uploads', 'new-dns.com/wp-content/uploads'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think you are right and normally I could update URLS by plugin but that doesnt work. And this is what I get in the database
Error
SQL query:

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = ( REPLACE( guid, 'magazine.americanmotorcyclist.com//wp-content/uploads', 'http://0vg.e15.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads' ) )

MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'f0vg42717902013.wp_posts' doesn't exist

Comment: Looking through the posts urls 

https://magazine.americanmotorcyclist.com/8190/8146-revision-v1/ 
I now see an appended (v1) to the url of the custom posts. Is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the name servers?

Comment: No i have not. I just moved the whole folder to a new domain and updated wp-config to the new database.